# insert range of values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE RECHARGE(
R_LVL VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
AMOUNT NUMBER,
POINTS_1 NUMBER
);

insert into RECHARGE
VALUES ('S1',(2950-4950),250);
```

i have the code above, and im trying to insert a range for the values in attribute amount, like this :

```
s1 : 2950-4950
s2: 5000-9950
s3: 10000-30000
```

so each lvl has it's own range of data, is it possible ?

Comment: Short answer is yes. But I would not store the values like that (Varchar) but rather in two separate columns with one from and one to column, so that the logic uses both columns with INT instead. Are you getting an error? And what kind of SQL server are you running? Technically, I would also assign an ID to the row itself that is the primary key, instead of using an varchar as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Number datatype cannot store special characters like `-`. You have to make it either VARCHAR or store 2 rows with single number like -

```
insert into RECHARGE
VALUES ('S1',2950,250);

insert into RECHARGE
VALUES ('S1',4950,250);
```

Or you can use 2 colums also like FROM-TO to show your date range like -

```
CREATE TABLE RECHARGE(
R_LVL VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
AMOUNT_FROM NUMBER,
AMOUNT_TO NUMBER,
POINTS_1 NUMBER
);

insert into RECHARGE
VALUES ('S1',2950,4950,250);
```

Then in SELECT query you can generate the result like you want.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't think of it this way, but i will update it

Answer (score 0):

Range consists of 2 values, store it in 2 columns.

The expression `(2950-4950)` equals to `-2000` (2950 minus 4950).

You should create two columns or have only just one of the boundaries of the ranges stored.
I suggest to store both values, because it is easier to query:

```
CREATE TABLE RECHARGE(
R_LVL VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
LOWER_BOUNDARY NUMBER,
UPPER_BOUNDARY NUMBER,
POINTS_1 NUMBER
);
```

You need to decide if the boundaries are closed (<=, >=) or open (<, >).

So you can query them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Recharge WHERE LOWER_BOUNDARY <= 2000 AND UPPER_BOUNDARY > 2000
```

Where 2000 is the value you are trying to find the range for.

You can make this thing more bulletproof by adding a few constraints:

- CHECK constraint to make sure that LOWER_BOUNDARY is lower than
  UPPER_BOUNDARY.
- UNIQUE on LOWER_BOUNDARY to eliminate repetition
- FOREIGN KEY to reference the UPPER_BOUNDARY from the previous range
  for the current ones LOWER_BOUNDARY (boundaries are continuous)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible
use the  next query

insert into RECHARGE
VALUES ('S1',(2950-4950),250)
('S2',(5000-9950),250)
('S3',(10000-30000),250)
;